# Stub a method with a generic class argument

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, mockito

I am trying to stub the following class:

```
public class MyFactory {
    ...
    public Publisher getPublisher(String arg1, String arg2, Class<? extends QueueMessage> msgClass) {
        do the magic...
    }
}
```

And here is (a short version of) the `Publisher` class:

```
public class Publisher <M extends QueueMessage> {

    public void publish(M message) throws IOException {
        publish(message);
    } 
}
```

I'd like to have two stubs in my test for two kinds of messages. Here is the stubbing code:

```
@Mock
private Factory factory;

@Mock
protected ThisMessagePublisher<ThisMessageType> thisMessagePublisher;

@Mock
protected ThatMessagePublisher<ThatMessageType> thatMessagePublisher;

when(factory.getPublisher(anyString(), anyString(), isA(ThisMessageType.class.getClass()))).thenReturn(thisMessagePublisher);
when(factory.getPublisher(anyString(), anyString(), isA(ThatMessageType.class.getClass()))).thenReturn(thatMessagePublisher);
```

It compiles correctly.

I then try to invoke the factory and the two publishers, hoping to verify one call for each publisher.

```
Publisher thisPublisher = factory.getPublisher("arg1", "arg2", ThisMessageType.class);
thisPublisher.publish(new ThisMessageType("Message"));
Publisher thatPublisher = factory.getPublisher("arg1", "arg2", ThatMessageType.class);
thatPublisher.publish(new ThatMessageType("Message"));

verify(thisPublisher).publish(Matchers.<ThisMessageType>any());
verify(thatPublisher).publish(Matchers.<ThatMessageType>any());
```

The test fails with the following error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
thisPublisher.publish(
    <any>
);
-> at ...
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Clearly, the second stubing is overriding the first one.

Diving into the `isA()` code and debugging shows that the inner generics are lost in the process of stubbing/calling/compiling. Scratching the back of my brain I seem to recall something about Java not being able to deal with inner generics like that.

So I tried stubbing the factory with `argThat()`, as follows, but the result is the same error as above.

```
when(Factory.getPublisher(anyString(), anyString(), argThat(new CustomTypeSafeMatcher<Class<ThisMessageType>>("Is class of ThisMessageType") {
    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(Class<ThisMessageType> aClass) {
        return aClass != null;
    }
}))).thenReturn(thisPublisher);
when(Factory.getPublisher(anyString(), anyString(), argThat(new CustomTypeSafeMatcher<Class<ThatMessageType>>("Is class of ThatMessageType") {
    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(Class<ThatMessageType> aClass) {
        return aClass != null;
    }
}))).thenReturn(thatPublisher);
```

Is there any way to achieve the stubbing and verification I'm aiming for. If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Could you provide a simplified version of your code for `Publisher`?

Comment: @Tunaki Done. Please see above.

Comment: I'm still not able to have the same error message as you (I have another one). 1. Try by removing `@Mock` on the `Factory` and instantiate it yourself. 2. If that does not work, post a simplified version of all the classes involved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in incorrect matcher:

```
isA(ThisMessageType.class.getClass())
```

Replace it with

```
eq(ThisMessageType.class)
```

See [matchers api](https://mockito.googlecode.com/hg-history/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html) for details.